# Azure C# Cast Message object as EventData

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm writing Unit Test for Azure Function.
I'm trying to call AzureFunction Run method but she take EventData as parameter.

I'm working with Message such as:

```
var data = "fullJsonBody";
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jsonBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>(data);
Message messageToSend = new(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonBody.ToString()));
messageToSend.Properties.Add("Prop1", "A");
messageToSend.Properties.Add("Prop2", "B");
messageToSend.Properties.Add("Prop3", "C");
messageToSend.Properties.Add("Prop4", "D");

_myModuleClient.SendEventAsync("Hub", messageToSend);
```

Now that i'm UnitTesting I want to directly call target Function such as:

```
public class MyAwesomeFunction
{
...

[FunctionName("MyMessages")]
    public async Task Run(
            [EventHubTrigger("HubTriggerExample", Connection = "HubConnectionStringExample", ConsumerGroup = "ConsumerGroupExample")]
            EventData[] events)
    {
        \\Work on Events
    }
    ...
}
```

By calling function as any other function in C#.

```
MyAwesomeFunction.Run(????);
```

Unfortunatlly I don't know how to generate an EventData object from a Message object.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it, I post what I have done for other.

You can create an EventData with a Byte Array, so I just had to serialize my Car object as string, then encode it as Bytes[] and then create my EventData:

```
var strCarObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CarObject);
byte[] carObjectByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCarObject);
EventData dataCarObject = new EventData(carObjectByte);
```

I don't need to use Message Properties in my case.